# angular + ngStomp + spring websocket controller not executed

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, stomp, spring-websocket, sockjs

I have searched through all the tutorials and did exactly as explained there, but I can't reach my controller.

Here is my websocket xml config:

```
<websocket:handlers>
    <websocket:mapping path="/updateHandler" handler="updateHandler"/>
    <websocket:sockjs/>
</websocket:handlers>

<websocket:message-broker application-destination-prefix="/app">
    <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/update">
        <websocket:sockjs/>
    </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
    <websocket:simple-broker prefix="/topic"/>
</websocket:message-broker>
```

I don't actually know do I need the handler, but without it stomp connection fails with ***"whoops! Lost connection to undefined".***
Any suggestion in this direction is also welcome.
Here is my empty handler:

```
 import org.springframework.web.socket.TextMessage;
        import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketSession;
        import org.springframework.web.socket.handler.TextWebSocketHandler;

        public class UpdateHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {

            @Override
            protected void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) throws Exception {
    }
}
```

And my controller

```
@RestController
public class WebSocketController {

    @MessageMapping("/update")
    @SendTo("/topic/messages")
    public OutputMessage sendmMessage(Message message) {

        return new OutputMessage(message, new Date());
    }
}
```

I am using ngStomp from angular as suggested:

```
    var message = {message: 'message body', id: 1};

            $scope.testWebSocket = function () {
                $stomp.setDebug(function (args) {
                    console.log(args + '\n');
                });

                $stomp.connect('/myAppContext/update', {})
                        .then(function (frame) {
                            var connected = true;
                            var subscription = $stomp.subscribe('/topic/messages', function (payload, headers, res) {
                                $scope.payload = payload;
                            }, {});


                            $stomp.send('/myAppContext/app/update', message);

                            subscription.unsubscribe();


                            $stomp.disconnect(function () {
                              console.error('disconnected');
                            });
                        }, function(error){
                            console.error(error);
                        });
            };
```

My Message Class:

```
public class Message {

    private String message;
    private int id;

    public Message() {

    }

    public Message(int id, String text) {
        this.id = id;
        this.message = text;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

My OutputMessage class:

```
public class OutputMessage extends Message {

private Date time;

public OutputMessage(Message original, Date time) {
    super(original.getId(), original.getMessage());
}

public Date getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(Date time) {
    this.time = time;
}
```

when I execute the testWebSocket() I get following output:

```
Opening Web Socket...
Web Socket Opened...

>>> CONNECT
accept-version:1.1,1.0
heart-beat:10000,10000

<<< CONNECTED
version:1.1
heart-beat:0,0
user-name:user@domain.com

connected to server undefined

>>> SUBSCRIBE
id:sub-0
destination:/topic/messages

>>> SEND
destination:/myAppContext/app/update
content-length:33

{"message":"message body","id":1}
```

Why connected to **server undefined**?
And why my controller never gets executed after sending a message?

I am using spring-4.1.4 with security-core-3.2.5 and Tomcat server 8.0.18

Answer (score 2):

As a non-pretty workaround, I moved websocket configuration to the Java config and it works.

Config below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/update")
                .withSockJS();
    }
```

I actually don't know why.